# Qlik Straight table that ignores selection but still show partial link to that selection?? Set analysis

Tags: selection, qliksense, qlik-expression, set-analysis

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I’m not too sure if this can even be done with Qlik’s model. But is it possible to use set analysis to ignore the current selection except one field linked to that selection (InvestmentID).
I have a table of owners and an investment table (**Image attached - D & E**) with the main link being the investment ID. One investment can have multiple owners but when you make a search/selection (using a filter pane) in qlik on one person then this list only shows that specific person selected table (**Image attached - A**) – there is no way to see the other linked investors.

I was wondering if it’s possible to still have a straight table display all linked owners to an investment despite one person being selected.
Hopefully the example below helps show what I am needing.

E.g.: An owner name search on Sam smith returns the current result but I would like to have something like the tables highlighted (**Image attached- table B or C**) that filters & shows linked owners to the InvestmentID.  So even though a search was done on Sam Smith, users would still be able to see Angela Russel details somewhere within the sheet.

I have been reading and searching for quite some time on set analysis and only see examples with numeric fields and aggregation functions like the below example thread. This is the reason for my post. If this is possible what functions could I use as I am not needing a sum or count.

https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Documents/Ignore-all-selections-except-some-specific-fields-using-Set/ta-p/1482031

Unrelated expression found online: sum({1<[Stock]={'Stock 1','Stock 3'}>} Amount)

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks heaps,

[image]

Comment: If you write something like this for Opt1 `sum({1<[InvestmentID]=p(InvestmentID)>} Amount)` ?

Comment: Thank you Stefan. This seems to work but does seem to provide extra IDs in some occasions